# Batch transfer rate upper bound in a channel?

Tags: ibm-mq

We use MQ (7.1.0.3, yes, it's an old version and we are planning for upgrade to v9 soon.....) for Q-Replication, and recently encountered MQ-tier transfer throttle. Specifically, msgs are stuck on XMITQ and cannot get to the other side quick enough. We used default settings for both `SDR` and `RCVR` channels for so long, and now realize MQ-tunning probably becomes necessary to deal with increase Q-Replication volume.

We understand a `batch` is cut when either one of the following conditions is met

- BATCHSZ (50) reached;
- BATCHLIM (5000KB) reached;
- SDR Q empty (This is less likely what we experienced, since XMITQ was backed up pretty high....).

Question is, how often does the MCA on sender side sends out a `batch` to the other side(without bothering piplines, we are still on v7.1, which seems like doesn't have pipeline feature anyway). Is a `batch` sent out immediately after it's cut, or it has to wait until the previous `batch` delivery is completed?

We are trying to estimate what would be the theoretical max MQ-transfer rate, given known network ping time (~20ms) and relatively stable RCVR-side MQ performance.

Btw, it's hosted on RedHat around version 6.8 (can't remember exact version, i'm not the sysadm....).

Comment: It would wait for the prior batch to be sent and ack'd before sending the next batch.  I understand that QREP can be setup to use multiple queues for sending the replication data, you can point each queue to a separate channel, this lets you send in parallel. There is also channel level compression that can be enabled, depending on your hardware on the sending side it may be able to compress things to send over more data on the wire, but with 20ms ping time the benefit may not be much, we have used it with much higher ping time with great success.

Comment: Also can you reference docs for what you are calling "pipelines", I am not familiar with this feature.

Comment: Pipelines are available from V5.2+. Read more here (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/ic13260_.htm). Without pipelining, as @JoshMc says, the channel has to wait for the completion of the previous batch before it can send even message 1 for the next batch. With pipelining, the channel can send as many messages from the next batch as it can while waiting for the previous batch to commit. It cannot start the commit process for batch2 until batch1 commits. It is useful in cases where the bottle neck is the commit processing.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for correcting me Morag (btw, your slides were super helpful when i was scratching my head trying to understand what happened to our QRepl-MQ usage, so thanks for for sharing the knownledge :)). I saw the link under windows before and naively thought linux doesn't have it... Well, according to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_properties_qmanager.htm it's probably configurable through config file.

Comment: According to what QRepl reports, in a 30-sec window the max msg transfer rate is under 4MB/sec, so our network bandwidth (10Gb link) is definitely underutilized on average. We have gigantic TX from time to time, and more frequently when we encountered MQ-transfer throttle, but i'm not familar with the exact formula translating TX-size to MQ-msg-size, yet. Anyway, sounds very tempting to turn-on pipeline, after bumping up `BATCHSZ`/`BATCHLIM` and compression.

Comment: @JoshMc always appreciate your quick and helpful response! One more newbie question, is it safe to restart a channel (stop + start, i haven't found a restart cmd...), even with non-empty (XMIT-/RCVR-)Q? Should channel listener be restarted as well? From my testing and understanding of (ibm) mq, restarting channel should be a safe operation, it's just not finding any official document saying so makes a newbie little uncertain.... thanks

Comment: For persistent messages it should always be safe. For non- persistent messages it MAY depend on the `NPMSPEED` setting.   In some cases the channel could  drop non- persistent messages.   `STOP CHL(XYZ)` with no `MODE` specified should be safe even for non- persistent messages from the SDR side.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @JoshMc. We use `DEFPSIST=YES` for all Qs used in QRepl, since we can't afford to loss data....

Comment: `DEFPSIST` is only a default if an application specifies nothing or  specifies as queue default which is the default if nothing is specified.    If an app specifies persistent or non persistent this is what the message will be,  the queue attribute will not override it.

Comment: I am not aware of what qrep does.   One thing to check is to look at the channel status,  if curseqno and lstseqno increase and match then persistent messages are being sent across the channel,  if only curseqno increases then non persistent messages are being sent across the channel.   If you see persistent messages are being sent it does not mean there is not non persistent mixed in since lstseqno will update to match curseqno with each persistent message even if the curseqno has increases previously with non persistent messages.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc, i just checked our QRepl config (IBMQREP_ IBMQREP_CAPPARMS.MSG_PERSISTENCE) and can confirm we are using persisted msg . https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.repl.qrepl.doc/topics/iiyrqctbrcapparm.html

Comment: Increasing parallelism
Use multiple Q Capture programs to parallelize traffic. You can set up multiple Q Capture schemas so that horizontal subsets of rows from a table, tables, or groups of tables are replicated using independent Q Capture programs and log readers. Each program can use a separate set of send queues, or even a separate queue manager, to speed the transfer of change messages. This configuration can improve performance and achieve higher throughput, for example, with very large source tables or on a large sysplex.

Comment: From https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_10.2.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.repl.qrepl.doc/topics/iiyrqctbcschemas.html

Comment: Yep, totally agree that's the right long-term solution, and we've been doing that already :). There's also legacy design preventing us pushing this front as much as we'd like, and we are slowing removing those obstacles (yes, referential integrity, enforced FK, etc.....).

Comment: Maybe a little tangential to this topic, are you aware of any features enabling single `XMITQ` sending the same msg to multiple `RCVR-Q`s? that would be a great feature for scaling out QReplication (of course still QRepl to wrap up everything...), capture once and replay n-times. I wouldn't argue against the idea of just using multiple QCapture program, or using event-publishing, or QRepl should use pub-sub/etc.  just curious~

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185335/discussion-between-joshmc-and-fall14123).

Comment: @JoshMc i think i _may_ find the answer to our problem. Insufficient tcp SDR/RCVR buffer-size. Sounds like NETTIME only reports the duration on SDR side between "end of batch" and "received ACK", minus process time on RCVR. So the additional RRT to transfer a batch is not really measured, unless throttle happens, like what we experienced so far.

Comment: We don't specify any additional TCP stanza, so the default 32kByte is in-use. We have avg msg size of 2kByte, about 20ms ping time, so sending a batch of 100 requires about 7 trips (140ms), pretty close to what we've been seeing so far.

Answer (score 0):

Live post updating our findings

1. `MAX_TRANS` *might* not be accurate and probaly won't help us much. `MAX_TRANS` controls the rate QCapture puts msg onto sendQ (IBM KC [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.repl.qrepl.doc/topics/iiyrqcapasnqcapprmds.html#iiyrqcapasnqcapprmds__max_trans)). Our problem, is MQ transfer rate throttle. With our config "`TRANS_BATCH_SZ=1`+`MAX_TRANS=128`+`COMMIT_INTERVAL=500`+`MONITOR_INTERVAL=30000`" (all collected from qcapture log, pretty sure those are config in-use), we would expect `MQ_MESSAGES` no more than around 8K (128 tx/sec * 2 * 30sec), but in fact our `IBMQREP_CAPQMON.MQ_MESSAGES` constantly surpasses 20K most of the time.... It's also possible those extra messages are results of LOBs, since we use `LOB_SEND_OPTION=S`, to avoid the hassle handling LOB_TOO_BIG error....
2. larger than 1 `trans_batch_size` requires `LOB_SEND_OPTION=I` (IBM KC [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.repl.qrepl.doc/topics/iiyrqcapasnqcapprmds.html#iiyrqcapasnqcapprmds__max_trans)), which is a blocker for us.
3. [added on Dec.20] An interesting thought occurred to me, **if the second batch is not *constructed* until the previous batck ACK comes back, and assume the following**, then the root problem might come from SDR-side.

   - on SDR-side it takes (relatively) fixed time to add a message to batch (eg. 0.95ms);
   - fixed ping-time of 20ms;
   - 0 delay on RCVR-side, meaning RCVR-side immediately sends back ACK.

   Using default `BATCHSZ=50`, it would take `0.95ms*50+20ms=67.5ms` for each batch to complete, yielding about `14.8 batch/sec`, or `14.8*50=740 msg/sec`;

   Using `BATCHSZ=100`, it would take `0.95ms*100+20ms=115ms` for each batch to complete, yielding about `8.7 batch/sec`, or `8.7*100=870 msg/sec`.

   Those numbers seem to match our observation/experiment, but need to verify if the assumptions are valid.