# Batch transfer rate upper bound in a channel - batch creation start trigger

Tags: ibm-mq

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799558/batch-transfer-rate-upper-bound-in-a-channel) stackoverflow question i understand a `batch` is sent out one at a time (without bother pipeline in this discussion), meaning, a second `batch` won't be sent until the first one is delivered.

My follow up question is, what condition starts a `batch creation process`. If i understand correctly (i could obviously be wrong....), a `batch` is created/cut, or let's call it a `batch creation process` is *completed*, if `BATCHSZ reached`, or `BATCHLIM reached`, or `BATCHINT (=/=0) reached`, or `XMIT-Q is empty`, but what starts a `batch creation process`. Is the `batch creation process` synchronous or asynchronous to batch transfer? Does `batch creation process` start only after the previous batch is delivered (synchronous), or it's totally decoupled from the previous batch (eg. while the previous batch is still in transfer)?

This is a sibling/follow up question to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799558/batch-transfer-rate-upper-bound-in-a-channel). The intention is to estimate our QRepl-MQ-transfer upper limit. As documented in entry "[added on Dec.20]" in the first (self-)answer in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799558/batch-transfer-rate-upper-bound-in-a-channel), our observation seems support the `batch creation process` starts synchronously AFTER the previous batch transfer is complete, but i couldn't find ibm references documenting the details......

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> our observation seems support the batch creation process starts
>   synchronously AFTER the previous batch transfer is complete, but i
>   couldn't find ibm references documenting the details.

Yes that is how it works.  If a 2nd batch started before the 1st batch finished then you would have newer messages jumping in front of older messages, which could cause all kinds of issues.

Yes, I know, applications are not suppose to rely on messages coming in a logical order (i.e. 1,2,3,etc.) but they do.

Think of MCA (Message Channel Agent) which is the process getting messages from the XMIT the same as a security guard at a store on Black Friday.  He lets in 50 people form the line (batch). After many people leave the store, he lets in another 50 people into the store.  Would you want ASYNC batching of the line at the store - absolutely not.  The security guard wants order not chaos.

The same is true for MQ's MCA.  It creates a batch of "n" messages, sends them, acknowledges them, then goes onto the next batch.